# Bookmarklet In New Window?

Tags: bookmarklet

I want to add a bookmark that open a webradio in a new window.

I tried the following code :

```
javascript:window.open('http//www.franceinter.fr/player',width=600,height=600,toolbar=no');
```

But i does not work.

Any idea why ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just had to add :

```
'_blank'
```

=>

```
javascript:window.open("http://www.franceinter.fr/player",'_blank','width=600,height=600,toolbar=no');
```